# How to disable GitLab build caching for a job

Tags: caching, build, continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-delivery

In GitLab there seem to be some sort of build cache.

For example, I have a job which builds and tags a docker image. The job succeeds and build log looks normal, but the image isn't actually created in the runner. Same thing with files: writing to file, which doesn't exist after job finishes. I suspect the build uses some kind of cache, as it executes so fast in these scenarios.

This behavior seems to manifest most often with detached pipelines, tag pipelines and when pipelines points to same commit via different refs in general.

How do I disable job caching and force the side effects to happen?

Answer (score 16):

According to GitLab's [documentation on caching](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#disable-cache-for-specific-jobs) you can try:

```
job_name:
  cache: []
  ...
```

Comment: Now the document changed to:

    job:
      cache: []

Comment: Indeed it should be `cache: []`

Comment: `cache config should be a hash`

Comment: The documentation is wrong, you should use `cache: {}` which specifies an empty _hash_ (`[]` is an empty list).

Comment: in 2023, and gitlab 16, `cache: {}` doesn't work, `cache: []` does work. documentation was changed here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/67881

Answer (score 1):

In config.toml file use the following configuration parameter :

```
[runners.docker]
...
disable_cache = true
...
```